# How do I allocate more memory to the boot process?

Tags: boot, grub2, thunderbolt

Normally when I boot into Ubuntu, everything works perfectly fine. Today, I enabled Thunderbolt support in my BIOS. After this, when I booted into Ubuntu from GRUB, I immediately got an error: "error: out of memory", after which the system hung. When I took a closer look at what changed due to enabling Thunderbolt support, I noticed the following

```
Extra bus reserved: [56]->[106]
Reserved Memory: [356]->[737]
Reserved PMemory: [1184]->[544]
```

Disabling Thunderbolt support fixed the issue. I'm assuming that because the system is reserving more memory at boot-time, Ubuntu is unable to boot. Is there a way to manually increase the memory available to Ubuntu's boot process?

Comment: First what version of Ubuntu are you using? How can you boot what is not there, thunderbolt took the memory.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1. I also forgot to mention, I have 32 GB total RAM, so my total available memory should be more than enough.

Comment: Those 32Gb is not the memory it is referring to. This is not an Ubuntu problem but hardware: your bios should have a "Thunderbolt Reserved Memory" and that is probably set too low.

Comment: I see, I just tried increasing it to a few different values, and unfortunately my computer won't even POST when I do. I guess I'll give up on thunderbolt support on Ubuntu for now, bit thanks for the help!